# trouble with selecting from database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select info from my database with codeigniter. Here is the code:

```
public function getContent($table_name){

  $show = false;
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($table_name));
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      $show = $query->result_array();
    }
  return $show;
  }
```

I get an error from mysql:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''main_db'' at line 1
>
> SELECT * FROM 'main_db'
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Staz1\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 331

I think that the problem is that the query has 'main_db' with apostrophes. When writing the query directly into the sql section in phpmyadmin that was the problem that I encountered (it only works if written with no apostrophes or with backticks).

If this is indeed the issue - how do I send the query without the apostrophes?

Comment: `?` escapes user-input values. It is not to be used for table names, or anything else. You could create a whitelist for your table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getContent($table_name){
  return $this->db->from($table_name)->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Can you not just return the result array?

Comment: @rybo111 yeah you can